# nexus OSS 3.3.0-01 keeps falling over

Tags: nexus

My team has been using nexus oss version 2 (currently on 2.14.2-01) for a very long time without any hick-ups and we like it.

For another project we need support for Docker and decided to give nexus oss version 3.3.0-01 a go. Unfortunately, this falls over a couple of times per day and i don't know how to debug this. Are other people having the same problem with this version? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Team have the same issue in our nexus 3. he just falling in a random times, yesterday we noticed that the ram in the server is in 95% usage so we increase the ram (It's virtual machine). until now the nexus didn't fall but I can't guarantee to you that our problem will not come back.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, we increased the RAM from 2 GB to 4 GB and went from 1 core to 2 cores. That helped, it's now up for 2 days without crashing. I hope it stays that way.

Comment: @Sam  My pleasure :)

Comment: After some more trouble we decided to move the nexus 3 to a dedicated VM with the before mentioned resources. Since then we haven't noticed any outages. It seems to be resource hungry and doesn't like to share.